# Software developer positions equivalents in German

Tags: terminology, technical-terminology, software

What are the equivalents in German for software developer positions: junior developer, middle developer, senior developer, lead developer?

Comment: Are this expressions well defined in English? I'm in doubt. See e.g. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/117179/what-is-the-job-title-hierarchy-amongst-software-engineers?lq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

afaik we Germans use the English expressions for job titles. But if you would like to translate them directly, you could say:

- junger Entwickler / junior Entwickler
- Entwickler
- erfahrener Entwickler
- Entwicklungsleiter

But I guess nobody uses a German equivalent for junior/senior developer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Also I've seen at heise.de term "Führender Entwickler" - is it "senior developer" or "lead developer" equivalent?

Comment: I would say it's `lead developer` but I never heard that term before. If you want to use `Führender Entwickler` be careful - cause with `Führen` or `Führender` people always quick associate that with the fuehrer. And that's defenitely no association you would like to have with your job title.

Comment: @BertramNudelbach: Seriously? The word "führen", and other words related to it, including very concretely the word "Führer" (as a short form of "Reiseführer" (travel guide) or "Bergführer" (hiking guide)) are commonly used in nowadays' German and, aside from situations where it's intentionally used as some kind of a pun, I doubt anyone would really make the connection to Hitler's title. The more critical misunderstanding that I see arising from "Führender Entwickler" is that is sounds rather like a quality assessment, as if the developer had proven to be the best ("führend") based on ...

Comment: ... some competition, and with respect to his or her skills and knowledge. At least, that would be my first association when I hear "Führender Entwickler", as opposed to the intended meaning of a "development team leader" ("Anführer", "Leiter"). So, @ArtemIzyumov, you may want to be careful with "Führender Entwickler", but IMHO not for the reason proposed by Bertram.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at monster.de, and search for "Java".

I would add "Softwareentwickler" to Bertram's answer.